# How would I combine C and Objective-C in the same file?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

I'm trying to make a Lua compiler for Mac OSX with an interface written in Objective-C and the Lua source code written in C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You already are combining C and Objective C.  No extra effort is needed.

Comment: To expand on this very slightly, you can make C calls or put C functions anywhere you like in an Objective-C source file — even between the @implementation/@end.

Comment: Also, if you add Objective-C to a .c source file, change the extension of the file to .m so that the compiler knows what to expect.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is a proper superset of C.  Any C you write in an Objective-C file is perfectly valid.

Comment: Objective-C has no keywords beyond the C keywords? I'd be delighted if Objective-C is truely a superset of C, but I have my doubts..

Comment: that would make it a subset? The point is, all the C keywords are Obj-C keywords, Not all Obj-C keywords are C keywords.

Comment: @R..: Objective-C keywords are prefixed with "@", which isn't a legal part of an identifier in C, so you won't run into a case where a C variable name conflicts with an Objective-C keyword, for example.